# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, canvas

My application stop and I ge Binary XML file error on line #0. It`s kinda weird, because I didn't see problem like this with line 0, so I need your help, everyone. Thanks!
This Works Fine On API greater than 20 only lower than API devices is crashing the application

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.vickyy.iwasframed, PID: 7818
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vickyy.iwasframed/com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.ImageSize}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.CustomFrame
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.CustomFrame
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.ImageSize.onCreate(ImageSize.java:31)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:574)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.ImageSize.onCreate(ImageSize.java:31) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7818 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

this is xmlFile

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/AppColor"
tools:context="com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.FrameActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/ActionBarColor">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ActionBarColor">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/ButtonColor"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="8sp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="USE IMAGE SIZE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WIDTH:"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HEIGHT:"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MAT OVERLAP:"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>




    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/edtWidth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtX"
        android:textSize="10sp"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    </EditText>





    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/edtHeight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtX"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/edtOverlap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtX"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <com.example.vickyy.iwasframed.CustomFrame
        android:id="@+id/imgFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/flower"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is the custom class that i code for draw rectangle with double and triple Mat

```
public class CustomFrame extends AppCompatImageView{


Paint paint;
int top,left,right,bottom;
Context context;
public CustomFrame(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    this.context=context;
}

CustomFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

CustomFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("Params", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int color = sharedPreferences.getInt("color",R.color.black);
    int canvasW = getWidth();
    int canvasH = getHeight();
    Point centerOfCanvas = new Point(canvasW / 2, canvasH / 2);
    int width = sharedPreferences.getInt("width",0);
    int height = sharedPreferences.getInt("height",0);
    int overLap=sharedPreferences.getInt("OverLap",0);
    boolean start=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("start",false);


    int rectW = width*75;  //convert to pixel
    int rectH = height*75;
    left = centerOfCanvas.x - (rectW / 2);
    top = centerOfCanvas.y - (rectH / 2);
    right = centerOfCanvas.x + (rectW / 2);
    bottom = centerOfCanvas.y + (rectH / 2);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
/*    if(start) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }
    else{

    }*/
    paint.setStrokeWidth(overLap);
    int l,t,r,b;
    int tripleLeft,tripleTop,tripleRight,tripleBottom;



    boolean doubleMat = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("DoubleMat",false);
    boolean tripleMat = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("TripleMat",false);

    if(doubleMat){
        int matHeight = sharedPreferences.getInt("MatHeight",0);
        int matWidth = sharedPreferences.getInt("MatWidth",0);
        int thickness=sharedPreferences.getInt("Doublethickness",0);
        int matW = (width)*75;
        int matH = (height)*75;
        int matw=matW-overLap;
        int math=matH-overLap;
         l = centerOfCanvas.x - (matw / 2);
         t = centerOfCanvas.y - (math / 2);
         r = centerOfCanvas.x + (matw / 2);
         b = centerOfCanvas.y + (math / 2);
        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(color);
        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        paint1.setStrokeWidth(thickness);      //inside

        paint.setStrokeWidth(overLap);  //mat

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("MatHeight",math);
        editor.putInt("MatWidth",matw);
        editor.commit();

        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(l, t, r, b, paint1);

    }
    else if(tripleMat){
        int matHeight = sharedPreferences.getInt("MatHeight",0);
        int matWidth = sharedPreferences.getInt("MatWidth",0);
        int dThickness=sharedPreferences.getInt("Doublethickness",0);
        int tThickness=sharedPreferences.getInt("Triplethickness",0);

        int matW = (width)*75;  //-2 here
        int matH = (height)*75;

        int matw=matW-overLap;
        int math=matH-overLap;

        l = centerOfCanvas.x - (matw / 2);
        t = centerOfCanvas.y - (math / 2);
        r = centerOfCanvas.x + (matw / 2);
        b = centerOfCanvas.y + (math / 2);  //inside

        int tripleWidth=(width)*75;
        int tripleHeight=(height)*75;

        int tmatw=tripleWidth-dThickness-overLap;
        int tmath=tripleHeight-dThickness-overLap;

        tripleLeft=centerOfCanvas.x-(tmatw/2);
        tripleTop=centerOfCanvas.y-(tmath/2);
        tripleRight=centerOfCanvas.x+(tmatw/2);
        tripleBottom=centerOfCanvas.y+(tmath/2);

        Paint triplePaint=new Paint();
        triplePaint.setColor(color);
        triplePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        triplePaint.setStrokeWidth(overLap);

        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(color);
        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);


        paint1.setStrokeWidth(dThickness);      //inside
        paint.setStrokeWidth((int)tThickness);  //mat

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("MatHeight",tmath);
        editor.putInt("MatWidth",tmatw);
        editor.commit();

        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, triplePaint); //outer
        canvas.drawRect(l, t, r, b, paint1);  //inside
       canvas.drawRect(tripleLeft,tripleTop,tripleRight,tripleBottom,paint); //outside

    }
    else {

   /*     Rect r=new Rect(left,top,right,bottom);
        //left
        canvas.drawLine(r.left,r.top,r.left,r.bottom,paint);
        //top
        canvas.drawLine(r.left,r.top,r.right,r.top,paint2);
        //right
        canvas.drawLine(r.right,r.top,r.right,r.bottom,paint);
        //bottom
        canvas.drawLine(r.left,r.bottom,r.right,r.bottom,paint2);*/

       // canvas.drawLine();
       // String text=String.valueOf(overLap);
       canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    //   canvas.drawText(text,left,bottom,paint);
     }

   }

 }
```

Comment: The constructors in `CustomFrame` must be explicitly `public`.

Comment: Are you sure your package name `com.example.vickyy.iwasframed` is correct?

Comment: @Muhammad have you posted the full xml file??

Comment: yes i posted full xml file on the last of file i declare custom class tag

Comment: thnkx its wokred when constructor goes to public thnkx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructors need to be public.  It can't access a private constructor when inflating.  Particularly the 2 variable one (your one variable is the only public one right now).

Comment: thnkx its wokred thnku